# Filter customers by custom attribute in admin grid

Tags: magento2, customer, collection, uicomponent, customer-grid

I added custom attribute to customer and now I want to filter customers by that attribute in admin grid (admin->customers). I want to user see only customers which custom attribute has specific value.

Filtering should be done before loading all customers, not with Filters button.

To be more specific, I just need a way to dump some rows from customers list based on some condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

I filter customers in Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column in prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) function where I print the value of custom attribute. As I have $dataSource which contains all customers, I remove from array the one that I don't want to show based on condition.

Important think is that after removing from array, you have to reindex array.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: more details please

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
  private $customerSetupFactory;

public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
    $setup->startSetup();
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'your_attributes', [
            'label' => 'Your Label',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'type' => 'int',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true, 
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true, //This is what you looking
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
            'option' => ['values' => ['Text1', 'Text2']],
        ]);

       $setup->endSetup();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is okay if I want to filter with "Filters" button, but I need to filter Customers before they are loaded.